# How to Use ParsleyJS with Browserify

Tags: browserify, parsley.js

I'm trying to browserify a module containing both jquery and parsleyjs.  So far I have this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('parsleyjs');
```

If I load this alone, the following line in ParsleyJS throws an `ReferenceError jQuery is not defined` exception:

```
window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.en = jQuery.extend(window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.en || {}, {
```

I think I can use `browserify-shim` to put jQuery and ParsleyConfig in the global scope, but I could use some help with the details.  Also I would prefer a solution that avoids polluting the global scope.

TIA,
- Ole

Answer (score 1):

I will explain my own experience with this problem.

*This is not the best way to manage this, I will leave here some clues:*

Setup

```
npm init
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save parsleyjs
```

app.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
require('parsleyjs/src/i18n/es.js')
require('parsleyjs');
window.Parsley.setLocale('es');

var userFormValidator = require('./validators/userFormValidator.js');
var hello = require('./functions/hello.js');
//global.window.hello = hello;

if (typeof global.window.define == 'function' && global.window.define.amd) {
    global.window.define('hello', function () { return hello; });
    global.window.define('userFormValidator', function () { return userFormValidator; });
} else {
    global.window.hello = hello;
    global.window.userFormValidator = userFormValidator;
}
```

functions/hello.js

```
module.exports = function () {
    alert('hola');
}
```

validators/userFormValidator.js

```
module.exports = (function ($) {
    var _settings = {};
    var _rules = {};

    var init = function(settings) {
        _settings = {
            form : $('#usersForm'),
        };

        _rules = {
            fullname : {
                minlength : 3,
                maxlength : 80,
                required : "true",
            },
            email: {
                minlength : 3,
                maxlength : 255,
                type : "email",
                required : "true",
            },
        };
        _setup();
    };

    var _setup = function () {
        _settings.form.parsley();
        var validate = require('./validator.js');
        validate(_rules);
    };

    return {
        init: init,
    };
})(window.jQuery);
```

validators/validator.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
module.exports = function (rules) {
    $.each( rules, function( field,  constraints) {
        $.each( constraints, function( constraint,  value) {
            $('[name="' + field +'"]').attr('data-parsley-' + constraint, value);
        }.bind(field));
    })
}.bind($);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="usersForm">

        <label for="fullname">Full Name * :</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" />

        <label for="email">Email * :</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" />

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        userFormValidator.init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that the [ParsleyJS](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/) project has a test [browserify.js](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/test/env/browserify.js) that shows how to use ParsleyJS with browserify.  It does attach all the ParsleyJS objects to the `window` object, and requires that jQuery do so as well, but at least it works.  If anyone has a solution that does this without attaching to the window, please share.

Here are the steps you need to follow to get it working:

```
mkdir parsleyjs-test
cd parsleyjs-test
npm init (Answer the questions)
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save parsleyjs
npm install --save-dev beefy

touch index.js
```

CONTENTS OF `index.js`

```
window.jQuery = $ = require('jquery');
require('parsleyjs');
```

TEST WITH BEEFY:

```
 beefy index.js 8080
```

View results at:
    http://localhost:8080

You should see both jQuery and Parsleyjs in the global window namespace.  Use `ctrl-shift-I` to open the web developer tooling in firefox and click on console.  Type window in the command line (Bottom of firefox console) and you will see `window.jQuery` and `window.Parsley`, etc.

Cheers,
Ole